# Two Django websites on Windows Apache

Tags: django, apache, mod-wsgi

I am trying to host two Django websites on Windows (so no WSGIdaemonprocess). When I did host only one of them it worked perfectly. Now it still works (main path "/" named magazyn). But the second one (path "/awizacje" named awizacje) throws an Internal Server Error. Full error message in Apache logs looks like this:

```
C:\A\34\s\Modules\_decimal\libmpdec\context.c:57: warning: mpd_setminalloc: ignoring request to set MPD_MINALLOC a second time

[Mon Oct 11 14:57:35.251409 2021] [wsgi:error] [pid 6268:tid 992] [client 192.168.2.54:25532] mod_wsgi (pid=6268): Failed to exec Python script file 'C:/var/www2/awizacje/rootkat/awizacje/wsgi.py'.
[Mon Oct 11 14:57:35.251409 2021] [wsgi:error] [pid 6268:tid 992] [client 192.168.2.54:25532] mod_wsgi (pid=6268): Exception occurred processing WSGI script 'C:/var/www2/awizacje/rootkat/awizacje/wsgi.py'.
[Mon Oct 11 14:57:35.251409 2021] [wsgi:error] [pid 6268:tid 992] [client 192.168.2.54:25532] Traceback (most recent call last):\r
[Mon Oct 11 14:57:35.251409 2021] [wsgi:error] [pid 6268:tid 992] [client 192.168.2.54:25532]   File "C:/var/www2/awizacje/rootkat/awizacje/wsgi.py", line 19, in <module>\r
[Mon Oct 11 14:57:35.251409 2021] [wsgi:error] [pid 6268:tid 992] [client 192.168.2.54:25532]     application = get_wsgi_application()\r
[Mon Oct 11 14:57:35.251409 2021] [wsgi:error] [pid 6268:tid 992] [client 192.168.2.54:25532]   File "C:\\var\\www\\magazyn\\env39\\Lib\\site-packages\\django\\core\\wsgi.py", line 12, in get_wsgi_application\r
[Mon Oct 11 14:57:35.251409 2021] [wsgi:error] [pid 6268:tid 992] [client 192.168.2.54:25532]     django.setup(set_prefix=False)\r
[Mon Oct 11 14:57:35.251409 2021] [wsgi:error] [pid 6268:tid 992] [client 192.168.2.54:25532]   File "C:\\var\\www\\magazyn\\env39\\Lib\\site-packages\\django\\__init__.py", line 19, in setup\r
[Mon Oct 11 14:57:35.251409 2021] [wsgi:error] [pid 6268:tid 992] [client 192.168.2.54:25532]     configure_logging(settings.LOGGING_CONFIG, settings.LOGGING)\r
[Mon Oct 11 14:57:35.251409 2021] [wsgi:error] [pid 6268:tid 992] [client 192.168.2.54:25532]   File "C:\\var\\www\\magazyn\\env39\\Lib\\site-packages\\django\\conf\\__init__.py", line 76, in __getattr__\r
[Mon Oct 11 14:57:35.251409 2021] [wsgi:error] [pid 6268:tid 992] [client 192.168.2.54:25532]     self._setup(name)\r
[Mon Oct 11 14:57:35.251409 2021] [wsgi:error] [pid 6268:tid 992] [client 192.168.2.54:25532]   File "C:\\var\\www\\magazyn\\env39\\Lib\\site-packages\\django\\conf\\__init__.py", line 63, in _setup\r
[Mon Oct 11 14:57:35.251409 2021] [wsgi:error] [pid 6268:tid 992] [client 192.168.2.54:25532]     self._wrapped = Settings(settings_module)\r
[Mon Oct 11 14:57:35.251409 2021] [wsgi:error] [pid 6268:tid 992] [client 192.168.2.54:25532]   File "C:\\var\\www\\magazyn\\env39\\Lib\\site-packages\\django\\conf\\__init__.py", line 142, in __init__\r
[Mon Oct 11 14:57:35.251409 2021] [wsgi:error] [pid 6268:tid 992] [client 192.168.2.54:25532]     mod = importlib.import_module(self.SETTINGS_MODULE)\r
[Mon Oct 11 14:57:35.251409 2021] [wsgi:error] [pid 6268:tid 992] [client 192.168.2.54:25532]   File "C:\\Python39\\lib\\importlib\\__init__.py", line 127, in import_module\r
[Mon Oct 11 14:57:35.251409 2021] [wsgi:error] [pid 6268:tid 992] [client 192.168.2.54:25532]     return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)\r
[Mon Oct 11 14:57:35.251409 2021] [wsgi:error] [pid 6268:tid 992] [client 192.168.2.54:25532]   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1030, in _gcd_import\r
[Mon Oct 11 14:57:35.251409 2021] [wsgi:error] [pid 6268:tid 992] [client 192.168.2.54:25532]   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1007, in _find_and_load\r
[Mon Oct 11 14:57:35.251409 2021] [wsgi:error] [pid 6268:tid 992] [client 192.168.2.54:25532]   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 972, in _find_and_load_unlocked\r
[Mon Oct 11 14:57:35.251409 2021] [wsgi:error] [pid 6268:tid 992] [client 192.168.2.54:25532]   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 228, in _call_with_frames_removed\r
[Mon Oct 11 14:57:35.251409 2021] [wsgi:error] [pid 6268:tid 992] [client 192.168.2.54:25532]   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1030, in _gcd_import\r
[Mon Oct 11 14:57:35.251409 2021] [wsgi:error] [pid 6268:tid 992] [client 192.168.2.54:25532]   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1007, in _find_and_load\r
[Mon Oct 11 14:57:35.251409 2021] [wsgi:error] [pid 6268:tid 992] [client 192.168.2.54:25532]   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 984, in _find_and_load_unlocked\r
[Mon Oct 11 14:57:35.251409 2021] [wsgi:error] [pid 6268:tid 992] [client 192.168.2.54:25532] ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'awizacje'\r
```

My `httpd.conf` looks like this:

```
WSGIPythonHome "C:/var/www/magazyn/env39"
WSGIPythonPath "C:/var/www/magazyn/venv/Lib/site-packages;C:/var/www/magazyn/rootkat/"

    ServerName www.magazyn-stolarz.pl
    LoadFile "C:/Python39/python39.dll"
    LoadModule wsgi_module "C:/var/www/magazyn/env39/lib/site-packages/mod_wsgi/server/mod_wsgi.cp39-win_amd64.pyd"
    WSGIScriptAlias /awizacje "C:/var/www2/awizacje/rootkat/awizacje/wsgi.py"
    WSGIScriptAlias / "C:/var/www/magazyn/rootkat/magazyn/wsgi.py"

    <Directory "C:/var/www/magazyn/rootkat/magazyn/">
        <Files wsgi.py>
            Require all granted
        </Files>
    </Directory>

    Alias /static "C:/var/www/static/"
    <Directory "C:/var/www/static/">
        Require all granted
    </Directory>
    
    <Directory "C:/var/www2/awizacje/rootkat/awizacje/">
        <Files wsgi.py>
            Require all granted
        </Files>
    </Directory>

    Alias /statica "C:/var/www2/static/"
    <Directory "C:/var/www2/static/">
        Require all granted
    </Directory>
```

My wsgi.py settings in 'awizacje' project:

```
"""
WSGI config for magazyn project.

It exposes the WSGI callable as a module-level variable named ``application``.

For more information on this file, see
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/howto/deployment/wsgi/
"""

import os
import sys
import site

from django.core.wsgi import get_wsgi_application
#os.environ.setdefault('DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE', 'awizacje.settings')
os.environ["DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE"] = "awizacje.settings"

application = get_wsgi_application()

site.addsitedir('C:/var/www2/awizacje/venv/Lib/site-packages')
sys.path.append('C:/var/www2/awizacje')
sys.path.append('C:/var/www2/awizacje/rootkat')
```

What am I doing wrong? I sadly can't use Linux which would be pretty straightforward.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like what I was missing was appending directories BEFORE `get_wsgi_application()` command in `wsgi.py`

```
"""
WSGI config for magazyn project.

It exposes the WSGI callable as a module-level variable named ``application``.

For more information on this file, see
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/howto/deployment/wsgi/
"""

import os
import sys
import site

from django.core.wsgi import get_wsgi_application
#os.environ.setdefault('DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE', 'awizacje.settings')
os.environ["DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE"] = "awizacje.settings"

application = get_wsgi_application()

site.addsitedir('C:/var/www2/awizacje/venv/Lib/site-packages')
sys.path.append('C:/var/www2/awizacje')
sys.path.append('C:/var/www2/awizacje/rootkat')
```